# Is Meteor.js stable enough for production?

Tags: javascript, meteor, production-environment, stability

I was really amazed about's meteor.js features and ease of use, im really falling in love with it. I just wanted to know if you expert guys think it is stable enough for using it in production for a medium sized project.

Thanks for your advice!

Update Nov 2014:

Meteor 1.0 was just released, this is the first ready for production version finally, more on meteor check out [this link](https://www.discovermeteor.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[6 months with Meteor](http://thechangelog.com/why-meteor/) has the best answer to this question I've found so far.

Here are a few excerpts:

> Meteor can’t be used for all real-world apps just yet. Meteor doesn’t have server-side rendering yet, so it’s not ideal for sites that need to load very fast (like e-commerce 
>   sites) or work on underpowered devices (like older mobile phones).

...

> So I would say right now Meteor will be a perfect choice for a few apps (anything that strongly depends on real-time interactions), a great choice for most of them, and a very bad one for a few specific cases.

It sounds like Meteor is definitely promising and particularly well-suited for real-time essential web  apps, however it's not production ready for all web apps at the moment. At the time of writing this meteor is at version 0.7.0.1.

Comment: and another article: first 3 months with meteorjs :) http://howwedoapps.com//2014/11/18/first-3-months-with-meteorjs

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this, because use cases vary so much.

I have an in-house application running on Meteor, which is basically a web-based SMS client with address book, fully integrated with our custom, in-house CRM. The Meteor app has 25 simultaneous users, and has been used to send or receive 70,000 SMS messages over the past 5 months, with total downtime measurable in minutes (which was due to network outages, not a problem with the application or framework).

There are definitely missing features, but assuming the features you need are implemented, the framework can be stable enough for production.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on what you're doing and how many users will connect to it. Using the current version 0.6.x you will need to tweak things that maybe Meteor devs are going to tweak, like MongoDB operations. Also, many packages are going to be released in future that will help a lot some work you are going to build yourself right now (for e.g. the IronRouter that C. Mather is building is very complex to build but very useful if you need complex operations in your app, like subscribing automatically in certain views, building forms etc)

Comment: Thank you very much for that Gabriel, i agree completely, I'll wait til there's a 1.0 release of meteor to start using it for production purposes, for now I'll keep on playing with it